# Updating SVG image with mouse

Tags: css, svg

Let's say I'm developing a maze web app that loading a maze created by SVG.

[image: Sample Maze]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0wfh.png))

Now I want to be able to let the user use the mouse to fill the path of the maze as he or she drags her mouse. How do I go about updating the SVG dynamically as the user traces and how do I prevent anything from being drawn unless what the user is dragging is within the boundaries of the maze?

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/Bzamom

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow really.  Any automatic approach that works for any maze would be really complicated.  However, there is a simple approach that requires a lot of pre-preparation. You could just fill your maze with little squarish segments that light up as you mouse over them.